# How to make companion application to connect one android device to another android devices...?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-wifi

I want to make a companion application it will connect to two android device,It will uses Either Bluetooth Or WiFi, Once the devices are paired each other the communication (like data transfer,messages,etc)will be happen.

The application should be similarly  like   **Android Wear Companion App**.

Please send some suggestions for the application.
 At which network protocol will be the best for companion application Either WiFi or Bluetooth.
 Is any open source project is available for companion application

Answer (score 1):

Since the application will be for wearable devices the distance between the wearable device and mobile phone will be very low. So you can prefer Bluetooth. In Bluetooth you can opt for BLE(Bluetooth Low energy) for sending small messages to the wearable devices.